# Ancient Brewing Techniques

Tags: process

I'm a newbie! An art historian by day...soon to be home brewer by night and weekends. QUESTION:  Do you know of a brewer (home brewer or well known craft brewer) who is knowledgeable about ancient brewing techniques? I'm looking specifically for someone who's studied Egyptian brewing techniques and tools. Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: [Moving Lindsey's "thank you" answer to a comment] Thanks guys! I'll check in with both of them! - Lindsey - 3/23/10 @ 19:02

Answer (score 5):

Dr. Ernie Schyuler, Curator Emeritus of Botany, The Academy of Natural Sciences - does a lecture circuit in Philadelphia entitled: "The Origin and Evolution of Beer"

Answer (score 4):

Sam Calagione at [Dogfish Head Brewery](http://www.dogfish.com/).  He has made some beer with the old methods and knows people who have done studies on ancient brewing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

BYO had an [article](http://www.byo.com/stories/article/indices/17-brewing-history/2223-tutankhamun-ale-story) in the November 2010 issue about Egyptian brewing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he's a brewer, but Patrick McGovern's book *[Uncorking The Past](http://www.ucpress.edu/book.php?isbn=9780520267985)* covers a lot about these topics.

Answer (score -1):

New Scientist - December 2004

Chemical tests on ancient fragments of broken pottery show that Chinese villagers were brewing alcoholic drinks as far back as 7000 BC. That beats the previous record for the oldest evidence of brewing, found in Iran and dated at about 5400 BC. !!!!!